# no resources defined drbd

Tags: linux, debian, drbd

I have a problem with the configuration of drbd

[image]

[image]

someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your hostnames resolve correctly? I see you have the hostnames '***drbd-node1***' and '***drbd-node2***' in your resource configuration, but at your command prompt the hostname is '***node2***'. DRBD parses the configuration for its own hostname to know what it needs to do.

In your example, changing '`on drbd-node2`', to '`on node2`', should allow you to proceed.

You'll need to update the hostnames in '`/etc/hosts`', to match what you have in '`/etc/drbd.d/storage.res`', and run the following command:

```
# hostname node2
```

Alternatively, you can see what the kernel is currently using as the hostname and set those in your DRBD configuration:

```
# uname -n
```

If that still doesn't do the trick, make sure that '`/etc/drbd.conf`' is including the resources defined in '`/etc/drbd.d/`'. The defaults should be:

```
# grep include /etc/drbd.conf
include "drbd.d/global_common.conf";
include "drbd.d/*.res";
```

Comment: I changed but still the same problem

Comment: I added a bit on checking the hostname, and a bit on making sure your resource definitions are included in 'drbd.conf'. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please start drbd service if you did not yet:

   `service drbd start`
2. Please shutdown this resource:

   `drbdadm down storage`
3. Try to create storage:

   `drbdadm create-md storage`